# Downloading a file with File Transfer plugin -ionic-

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to download a file from the server using `File Transfer plugin`

My issue that get in the console of success function :

**download complete: file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/statsh.appliMobile/files/PICTURE.png**

but I didn’t find the file in my smartphone ( lenovo VIBE) after doing a research

I thought I will find it in this directory : **PC\Lenovo P1ma40\Phone storage\Android\data**

this is my code :

```
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';


...
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create(); 

        const url = 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2048-200.png';

        fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'PICTURE.png').then((entry) => {
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        }, (error) => {

        });
      }
```

Comment: You can't access this directory for read from explorer, use some path like this : `this.file.externalRootDirectory`

Comment: thank you for your comment I used externalRootDirectory also I can't see the file even in my smartphone but the file exist I can open it with file opner plugin

Comment: so I want the user can see the downloaded file

Comment: what's your mean about "see" ? Is your mean "open file"? Do you use cordova file opener?

Comment: yes I use cordova file opener plugin the user can see the file. but after closing the application he want to reopen the downloaded file he doesn't find it in his gallery of images if it is an image

Comment: Please see [Android File System Layout](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout)